# Camera and Gallery For Cross-Platform (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need To use camera/gallery in xamarin for Android/Ios. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, install plugin in your solution: "Xam.Plugin.Media"

For Camera write this Code and get File:

```
var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions() { SaveMetaData = true, PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight });
```

For Gallery write this Code and get File:

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions() { SaveMetaData = true, PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight });
```

This work For both Android & Ios Platform in Xamarin Commonly.